# xquery to parse a key value format pair XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I Have trouble to use xquery to parse a key value pair XML. The column is one element and value is the other element. The expected result that i want to get is shown below:

```
Status    year    Name 
ACCCESS   2016    Mike


declare @xml xml
set @xml='
<DATA>
   <NVPAIRS>
      <PAIR>
         <NAME>Status</NAME>
         <VALUE>ACCESS</VALUE>
      </PAIR>
      <PAIR>
         <NAME>year</NAME>
         <VALUE>2016</VALUE>
      </PAIR>
      <PAIR>
         <NAME>Name</NAME>
         <VALUE>Mike</VALUE>
      </PAIR>
   </NVPAIRS>
</DATA>
'
--????????????
select 
status = pd.value('/NAME="status"', 'varchar(50)')
from 
@xml1.nodes('//PAIR') as i(pd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the following query to shred your XML:

```
select pd.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ColumnName
     , pd.value('(VALUE)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ColumnValue
from  @xml.nodes('//DATA/NVPAIRS/PAIR') as i(pd)
```

Which would get the data in the following format in sql:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ColumnName ║ ColumnValue ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Status     ║ ACCESS      ║
║ year       ║ 2016        ║
║ Name       ║ Mike        ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Now you can use the above query along with PIVOT to pivot your data and it would look something like....

```
Select * 
FROM
    (
    select pd.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ColumnName
         , pd.value('(VALUE)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ColumnValue
    from  @xml.nodes('//DATA/NVPAIRS/PAIR') as i(pd)
    )a
       PIVOT (MAX(ColumnValue)
              FOR ColumnName
              IN  ([Status],[year],[Name])
              )p
```

Final result set would look what you are after:

```
╔════════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Status ║ year ║ Name ║
╠════════╬══════╬══════╣
║ ACCESS ║ 2016 ║ Mike ║
╚════════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.